# Global and Local variables JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How to get information that is inside a function, from outside a function

```
var x = 0;

function myFunction() {  
    x += 1 //When a button is clicked Javascript will add 1 to x, now x will have a value of 1

}

alert(x) //This returns 0, how to make it return 1
```

P.S Only pure JavaScript
P.P.S Try to make your answer simple, without a lot of code. Thanks :)

Comment: Wait until the function is executed, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be called `myFunction`, `myFunction()`, first before the alert. This is why you get 0. When this script is loaded the value of x is 0. Hence the alert will alert 0. Then each time a user clicks on the button you have referred to, the value of `x` would be incremented by 1. That being said, I think that you need something like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    // when the button will be clicked the value of x
    // would be incremented by one.  
    x += 1 

    // the new value would be alerted.
    alert(x);
}
```

Another way it would be this:

```
myFunction();
alert(x);
```

However, this doesn't make sense, since you need to increment the value of `x` each time the button is clicked and you don't need to force the execution of `myFunction`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call myFunction() first, e.g.:

```
myFunction();
alert(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, your function has to be executed for that. The function body only executes if invoked/called. So either create an IIFE function or call it later

```
myFunction();
alert(x); // now the value has been updated
```

By IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expresson), I mean

```
(function(){
  x += 1;
})(); // invoke
```

Answer (score 0):

start by colling your `myFunction();` and then you can get the value by `alert(x);`

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct in this situation - just call `myFunction();` before `alert(x)`, but just for completeness, the other option to "get information inside a function from outside it" is to return a value from the function:

```js
var x = 0;

function myFunction() {  
    return x + 1; // returns 0 + 1 = 1. Note x is still 0
}

var y = myFunction(); // y stores the return value of the function, i.e. 1
alert(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out:

http://jsfiddle.net/4taojgy7/

```
(function(){
  var x=10;
    function run(){
    alert(x);
    }
  run();
})();
```

Function 'run' can access only those variables which is in its scope. Even though variable 'x' defined in outside, but still it is accessible. You need to look into scope of a variable concept more. Hope that clarifies.